# How do you reconcile common C++ naming conventions with those of the libraries

Tags: c++, coding-style, naming-conventions

Most C++ naming conventions dictate the use of `camelCaseIdentifiers`: names that start with an uppercase letter for classes (`Person`, `Booking`) and names that start with a lowercase letter for fields and variables (`getPrice()`, `isValid()`, `largestValue`).  These recommendations are completely at odds with the naming conventions of the C++ library, which involve lowercase names for classes (`string`, `set`, `map`, `fstream`) and `names_joined_with_an_underscore` for methods and fields (`find_first_of`, `lower_bound`, `reverse_iterator`, `first_type`).  Further complicating the picture are operating system and C library functions, which involve compressed lowercase names in C and Unix and functions starting with an uppercase letter in Windows.

As a result my code is a mess, because some identifiers use the C++ library, C, or operating system naming convention, and others use the prescribed C++ convention.  Writing classes or methods that wrap functionality of the library is painful, because one ends with different-style names for similar things.

So, how do you reconcile these disparate naming conventions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One way it to adopt the C++ `naming_convention`, this is what most code examples in the literature do nowadays.

I slowly see these conventions move into production code but it's a battle against MFC naming conventions that still prevail in many places.

Other style differences that fight against old standards are using trailing underscores rather than `m_` to denote members.

Comment: The C++ naming convention has all identifiers (class and field names) in lowercase.  Can you point to C++ style guidelines that recommend this style?  The "C++ Coding Standards" and "The Elements of C++ Style" books don't.

Comment: I don't know of such a document, I derive the C++ naming convention from the STL (which is, obviously, part of the standard).

Comment: I agree with Motti: While I prefer the camelCase style, the STL is using the naming_convention, and as such, could be considered the "default" style for C++... But then Win32 API/.NET is PascalCase, and C API is all about six-length funny function names... So, in the end, pick up you poison... ^_^

Comment: An advantage of using the C++ standard library naming convention is that your own container-like classes become more easily compatible with STL containers. For example, you can use `back_insert_iterator` on a class having `push_back()`, but not on one having `pushBack()`.

Answer (score 22):

Diomidis, I share your pain and have spent a lot of time switching between different schemes over the years, trying to find something that works with the different libraries/frameworks that I use (MFC and/or STL/Boost).  When working with a single framework, such as the STL, you can try and copy the naming convention it uses, but when you introduce a different framework, it easily falls apart.

In the end I have adopted a single style for all new code that I write (based on the Google C++ style guidelines) and I refactor older code to use this style when appropriate.  You cannot reconcile the different naming conventions very easily, so don't waste time trying.  Enforce a scheme for your team/dept./company and stick to it - but don't get hung up on how 'ugly' the code may look when using a mixture of schemes.

The Google C++ guidelines are pretty good IMHO - with some minor amendments.  Check the guide out here:

https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Naming

Comment: I was thinking of using something similar to Google's guidelines, but they don't mix well with STL, that's why I asked the question.  I guess I got spoiled by Java's absolute order.

Comment: If I was lucky enough to develop in 'pure' STL then it wouldn't be a problem.  I went through a phase of using multiple styles depending on the target framework - fine until I started mixing STL/boost with MFC!  The Google style is as good as any I've seen, although I have tweaked it slightly.

Comment: don't rename the old code unless you want to change it all - you screw with diff/merge and it can hurt.

Comment: I become skeptic of the recommendations when I've read their recommendation to not use exceptions, I was like "wtf are they thinking, really"

Answer (score 4):

I tend to be a perfectionist when it comes to code style, and this has always bothered me.  I wish there were a universal standard, but there isn't.  In my professional career, I have found that as long as the programmers on an individual project are consistent, that is the best you can hope for.

Ultimately, I think it comes down to knowing from which library a method, object, or function comes from.  If you know that, then it becomes easy enough to remember which convention is used by that library, assuming the project doesn't include a lot of libraries.  I have tried adapting my own code to match that of the libraries I use, but it is always a moving target and just frustrating in the end.

Answer (score 4):

Why the need to reconcile? As long as the code compiles, and you can get work done, don't worry about it.

Comment: Because to some people (such as me), part of the enjoyment of being a programmer is the esthetics of code. My code is poetry, as long as I can make it so without detracting from the task at hand.

Comment: With varying code conventions you have to remember where an identifier comes from, in order to type it correctly.

Comment: Yeah, but when dealing with other people's code and 3rd party libs, it's impossible they will have the same conventions as you (and as each other), so at some point you just gotta buckle down, get used to it, and get some work done.

Comment: Diomidis Spinellis mentioned in another comment thread he was spoiled by the absolute naming convention in Java. I too had this same question after being spoiled by Java's and Ruby's strict naming conventions. As we all learned here C++ is a mashup of conventions that are difficult to reconcile.

Comment: As developers, we spent the majority of our time **reading** code. Conventions make that part of our job less time consuming and safer. Inability to impose those conventions onto 3rd party libraries is a non-issue: You hardly ever read/debug that 3rd party library code. If a 3rd party's library interface semantics are in conflict, you can either adapt, or leave a comment in code. When dealing with other people's code, conventions are what makes them adhere to the same rules you are.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, I would just use the library as-is and stick to your own coding style. You *could* wrap it, but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 3):

In the projects I am working on I follow to code conventions for my project. When I call something other I use API of that library.

I also would add that wrapping of library is a bad idea (there are a lot of them in the code base I am working on) because it is usually done by the developer who solve his own problem and as a rule it is inappropriate for usage by all other developers. From the other side high quality wrapping is expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Fav quote::

> The best thing about standards is that
>   there are so many to choose from!

My suggestion would be to take the library's convention that occurs in your company's code most often (probably the C++ library, which I believe boost sticks to as well), and make *that* your standard. Otherwise, you might as well not have one at all.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since we can't change the way the standard libraries are implemented, I guess we'll have to live with it. As for reconciling - while writing some Win32 API stuff a while ago, I tried naming my own methods in PascalCasing as it's done in the API, but it just didn't feel right. So I went back to naming my methods in camelCase. I agree it's a mess, but the other option is to adapt your style to every new framework or library you use, and then there's the issue that you mention of having more than one library using different conventions in a single project. So my advice is - stick to what feels right for your own methods and classes. Or - when in corporate environment - stick to your company's best practices and guidelines.

Comment: Nitpick: I don't believe the term 'camelCase' is widely used to distinguish lower vs. upper case for the first letter. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camelcase. I don't see the term PascalCase very often - no idea what the general implication is.

Comment: @Steve: Did you read that Wikipedia article you link to? Because in the very beginning it mentions the difference between camel case and pascal case, saying it's used by "some people". Well, I'm one of those people.

Comment: And here's a good reference to casing styles at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Doh - I skimmed too quickly. In other reading I see my experience (camelCase as a more generic term) is not the most common. That's what I get for nitpicking. :)

Answer (score 2):

I seem to recall reading a long time ago that they choose to make the standard library different from the recommended coding convention on purpose, to avoid naming collisions.  I can't find any reference that mentions that now, however.  I remember reading that you shouldn't use leading lowercase letters in type names because they were reserved for the standard libraries.  I assume something similar is going on with the use of underscores.  I really don't see multiple naming conventions as a problem, since it clearly separates the standard code from code in your project.  I always code stuff in my projects using capital camel case for types and lower camel case for methods/members.  My current workplace uses capital camel case for methods in addition to types, which irks me greatly.  But, they also like Hungarian warts, which even MS has disowned :P

Answer (score 2):

You should embrace the difference.

When people see the use of remove_copy_if, they will immediately know that this is an algorithm.  This is actually a positive feature as algorithms come with certain guarantees (or lack of).

We also use the naming convention for our own custom algorithms.