# Lowercase class names, variable names

Tags: c++

In an earlier question:

[How do you reconcile common C++ naming conventions with those of the libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/350419/2308693)

it has been suggested that we should use `class_name` for class names. My problem with this is this:

```
struct car {};
car car;  //<-- cannot name my vars like i want them
car car1; //<-- error
```

so I'm forced to name my variables like this:

```
car c;
```

I'm not sure if this makes my code more readable or not. On way would be to use uppercase class names:

```
Car car;
```

but then you are back to square one with name convention conflicts.

I'm looking for ideas to solve this.

By the way, I'm a huge fan of the `class_name` convention, and I want to use it. The only problem is the variable names as I mentioned.

Comment: How is `struct car {}; car car1;` an error? It's not a very good name (but neither is `car`), but it works just fine.

Comment: @delnan It's not an error by itself, it becomes an error because I create above it a variable with the same name as the class name. For integers, `int i;` is common and well understood. I'm not so sure about `car c;`

Comment: i wonder what convention did you end up with after 10 years

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct car {};
car car;         // not a good variable name, but legal
struct car car1; // no error
```

Coming up with a better variable name would be good no matter what you name the type. This depends on what you're actually using the variable for.

```
void shoot(Car target) {                     // in a game involving shooting at cars
void register(Car patient) {                 // in a program having something to with fixing cars
for (Car &potential_winner : participants) { // in a racing game
```

---

On upper-case type names; The types you define don't have to match the style of the standard library. Personally I prefer to have specialized, domain specific components be stylistically distinct from the generic components.

I like capitalizing application specific types. Whether I use `PascalCase` or `Caps_and_underscores` depends on the language.